# From mongoshell how to insert utc datetime and epoch values as utc datetimes into mongodb

Tags: mongo-shell

Trying to do a proof of concept of loading sample tick data into mongo db and the tick archive data is generally in utc and epoch and  need to load it as is and output as utc only not local datetimes.

How to insert  utc datetime and epoch in mongodb without being cast into utc again  and retrieve the 
same as utc only.

```
db.equity_ticks.insert(
{
"SNAPSHOT_DTTM" : Date("2013-07-09 19:00:00.000000"),
"CLOSE_DATE" : Date(15895) ,
"PREV_DAY_CLOSE_DATE" : Date(15895) 
}
```

instead it inserted the local CST and output as CST too !

> db.equity_ticks.find().pretty()

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52040942e5171b792b258ae8"),
"SNAPSHOT_DTTM" : "Thu Aug 08 2013 16:10:26 GMT-0500 (CDT)",
"CLOSE_DATE" : "Thu Aug 08 2013 16:10:26 GMT-0500 (CDT)",
"PREV_DAY_CLOSE_DATE" : "Thu Aug 08 2013 16:10:26 GMT-0500 (CDT)"
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is Date(15895)? I tried it, it always stores current date time, why do you use it?

Comment: its the epoch secs i.e. secs from 1/1/1970 0:0:0 etc and was using the date function to convert the epoch to utc datetime.. not working as you see..

Comment: Ok  found out the datetiume  part! <code><pre>                                 `> db.bug.insert( { "dateTime": new Date("04-16-2013 19:00:00") } )
> db.bug.find().pretty();
        "_id" : ObjectId("52055acf889999492527c828"),
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2013-04-16T05:00:00Z")
}
`</code></pre>

Comment: I just found out that this number 15895 is the days since 1970/01/01